# How do you show {$x \in \mathbb{R}|f_1(x)=f_2(x)$} is open?

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$

Assume $f_1,f_2: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable.

Assume $f'_i(x)=g(x,f_i(x))$ for $i=1,2$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Let $S=${$x \in \mathbb{R}|f_1(x)=f_2(x)$}. Show $S$ is open.

Here is my attempt:

Let $u \in S$. Then I want to show $\exists r>0$ such that the open ball $B_r(u) \subset S$.  I know that since $u \in S \implies f_1(u)=f_2(u)$.

But I am unclear how to get this open ball.

Comment: Open or closed?

Comment: The title says closed while the body says open. Which do you mean?

Comment: Changed it.  I meant Open.

Comment: No, the definition of S is correct.

Comment: Also, in a previous problem, I showed that S is closed.  Now I must prove it is also open.

Comment: @ClementC. $g$ does play a role because the 2nd parameter of $g$ is $f_i(x)$

Comment: Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem (the English name)

Comment: @ClementC. I cannot use that theorem because it assumes $\exists M > 0 $ such that $|g(x,f_1(x)-g(x,f_2(x)| \leq M|f_1(x)-f_2(x)|$

Comment: If I could make that assumption about $g$, then it makes sense.

Comment: But you can. Assume there is $x_0\in S$, and consider $[x_0-1,x_0+1]$. $g$ is $C^1$ on this interval, so Lipschitz.